# Groupby and count number of element in df depending on pattern

Tags: r, group-by, count

Hel lo I have a df such as :

```
Col1 Col2
Group1 Seq_1:(+)Sp1
Group1 Prot_1-A
Group1 Seq_1:(-)Sp2
Group1 Prot_1B
Group1 Seq_2:(-)Sp2
Group1 Seq_1:(+)Sp3 
Group1 Prot_1C
Group2 Seq_1:Sp5 
Group2 Prot_1-E
Group2 Prot_1G
Group2 Seq_2:(+)Sp5 
Group2 Seq_1:(+)Sp6 
Group3 Seq_1:(-)Sp7 
Group3 Prot_1H-AB
Group3 Seq_1:(+)Sp7 Prot_1Y
```

and I would like grouby each group in Col1:
- count the number of different `Col2` values that `do not have` a `(+)` or a `(-)` in its element.
- count the number of different `Col2` values that `do have` a `(+)` or a `(-)` in its element.

ex Group1:

- Nb seq with (+) or (-)  = 4
- Nb seq without (+) or (-) = 3

Group3:

- Nb seq with (+) or (-)  = 2
- Nb seq without (+) or (-) = 1

Comment: Yu can load `library(stringr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'Col1', get the `sum` of 'Col2' where there are `+` or `-` wrapped within `()`, and those without that

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Col1) %>%
    summarise(Sum_minus_plus = sum(str_detect(Col2, "\\([+-]\\)")),
              No_minus_plus = n() - sum(str_detect(Col2, '^Seq')))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Col1   Sum_minus_plus No_minus_plus
#  <chr>           <int>         <int>
#1 Group1              4             3
#2 Group2              2             2
#3 Group3              2             1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
"Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", "Group2", 
"Group2", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3"), Col2 = c("Seq_1:(+)Sp1", 
"Prot_1-A", "Seq_1:(-)Sp2", "Prot_1B", "Seq_2:(-)Sp2", "Seq_1:(+)Sp3", 
"Prot_1C", "Seq_1:Sp5", "Prot_1-E", "Prot_1G", "Seq_2:(+)Sp5", 
"Seq_1:(+)Sp6", "Seq_1:(-)Sp7", "Prot_1H-AB", "Seq_1:(+)Sp7 Prot_1Y"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Data tables allow expressions in `by` (or `keyby`) so you can set a grouping argument to those that do or do not contain `(+)` or `(-)` and then the `.N` special symbol to get counts:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, .N, keyby = .(Col1, Col2 %like% "\\([-+]\\)")]
```

Giving

```
     Col1  Col2 N
1: Group1 FALSE 3
2: Group1  TRUE 4
3: Group2 FALSE 3
4: Group2  TRUE 2
5: Group3 FALSE 1
6: Group3  TRUE 2
```